# Is there anyway to search for text on a page and then make the mouse click the page.. in Auto it.?

Tags: javascript, autoit

I know if i could access the dom this would be easy.. but i can't so what I want to is run around searching for text on a page then whne I know what line that text is.. i could move to the left or right a tiny bit and click a button.. so the problem is there seems to be no easy way to get the cursor to move to the same point that the search goes.. Been looking for a way to do this for many moons so it would really be appreciated if someone has any ideas that i can try.. Thanks  I have tried dang near everthing i could possilby do but no luck.

Comment: Can you give an example and code of your attempts so far?

Comment: All of my attempts have  been to use the firefox search box to find the text and hilite it.. and at that point I can copy the text to the clipboard and do whatever with it.. but there is no way that i can find to pinpoint the x, y coordinates to move the mouse to that piont so that I may click on it..

Comment: try looking at https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/ for firefox automation

Comment: Have looked at most that many times before.. but have yet to find anyone who could figure out how to tell the position of the search both horizontally and vertically on the screen so the mouse could be moved there for a click.. Normally I would ask at autoit.. but so far no one has solved it.. and I have been getting better asnwers from stackflow than from autoit.. but thanks for offering assist.

Comment: What about using ImageSearch? https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but as i read it appears that i need images for that.. what i am trying to do is search for a piece of text on a line then move the mouse to the right to a button and click that.. if I could determine the xandy of the text.. then its easy to move the mouse say 100x to left while keeping the same y and click.. but dont see how images can help me here..

Comment: Take a screenshot, crop down to the text you're searching for, and use that as a search image